# Virtual Directories in Windows File Sharing

Tags: windows, file-sharing, virtual-directory

I'm running a file share on Windows 7 professional, and I'd like to add a shortcut/virtual directory to other shares. For example, if someone connects to \machinename\share (call that folder A), I'd like a way to list folder B in folder A without folder B physically existing in folder A. In IIS I'd use a virtual directory, but those don't seem to translate to file sharing. Any suggestions?

I've also shared folder B, so if there's a way to "shortcut" from one share to another, that would work too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows you could use [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx) to make a folder somewhere else in the filesystem also appear in the folder you are sharing.  This really only applies if you are talking about files on the local system though.  You can't link to things on other systems.

```
mklink /d \MyDocs \Users\User1\Documents
```

If you want to have links to external systems you will want to look at DFS.  But that does require Windows server, and the linking can really only be done a one level.

Comment: Yeah...the symbolic link worked for my local machine but not for the machines from which I'm accessing the file (I don't want to ask them to allow that type of symbolic link). Guess Windows Server is where it's at. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is Distributed File Services, which isn't supported on Windows 7. It IS supported on the Server versions of Windows, though.

Answer (score 0):

> I've also shared folder B, so if there's a way to "shortcut" from one share to another

There sure is :)

Open share A, right click -> New -> Shortcut then put the UNC path to share B